# Grunt dist with git and multiple servers

Tags: angularjs, git, gruntjs, yeoman

I am about to start using Yeoman with Angular.js for a project that has PHP as the backend. I know I can use Grunt to minify all my files and get it ready for production. My question is, how do I handle that properly with Git?

Right now I have three servers (development, staging, production) and instead of uploading files with FTP, I just pull from my Github repository. This works fine, but with Yeoman and Grunt, I don't want all the files that is brings along for development, I just want the distribution files on my staging and production servers.

Is there a way to do this with Git?

Answer (score 0):

The `git subtree` command is an option that should accomplish what you want.

[Check out this page for more information](http://yeoman.io/learning/deployment.html) and a few other options for deployment of the production code.